# Is there an overview of several logical systems?

Tags: reference-request, logic

I've heard about many kinds of logic like combinatory logic, relevance logic, higher order logic, paraconsistent logic... but I don't know anything about those logical system except higher order logic.

Is there an overview or meta-tutorials about all logical systems? In particular, I'd like to know why those logic system are made and what their applications are.

How to classify them?

Comment: The "Handbook of Philosophical Logic" by Gabbay et al. (several volumes) is a very nice source to get into a specific non-classical logic (the volumes are divided in surey articles of several non-classical logics). For a short introduction of the landscape of non-classical logics, I recommend Priest's book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the best overview from a mathematicial perspective is Graham Priest's [An Introduction To Non-Classical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521854334). The second edition is much more detailed, and if you only want a survey, you may prefer the first edition, if you can find it.

Susan Haack's [Philosophy of Logics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521293294) is more philosophical, but still good for an overall impression of the subject.

Another excellent, and more recent book on the subject is [Philosophical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691137897), by John Burgess. All three of these books are written by philosophical logicians, perhaps because the motivation for studying non-classical logics often arises from philosophical concerns.

Comment: thanks. is there a pdf or online version?
I can't afford this now

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but the many articles on varient logics at the [Stanford Encylopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/) are excellent.

Comment: @snowcake and icejelly: For an introductory treatment, you may want to look at Eric Schechter's book **Classical and Nonclassical Logics** (2005). http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/logics/

Comment: @snowcake: Take a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2147/most-helpful-math-resources-on-the-web There you can find one of "the most useful math resources from the web"